# Find and replace or remove HTML <li> tag using sed in Linux

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, html

I need to remove the following html `<li>` tag in many index.html pages.

```
<li>
                      <a href="https://forward.global.ssl.fastly.net/contributoragreements/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClickTracking', 'TopNav_Contact_Editorial', window.location.href]);">Editorial</a>
                    </li>
```

I need to remove this recursively in many files. So I guess using regex in sed in linux is the best option. I tried in many ways however could not find a solution. There are other `<li>` tags inside the index.html file but they should not be edited in anyway. Only the above mentioned tag should be removed.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the criteria for removing the `li` node from the document? Is is that it contains that particular `a` node? Is the `a` node in that case to be identified by its `href` or `onclick` attributes or its value, or all?

Comment: The url is a 404 and the site has many of this urls inside index.html files. Its better if we can remove the whole li tag.

Comment: I would [recommend against parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Instead, I suggest `python3` with `beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: @RavinduPrashan please ***[edit]*** your question and explain exactly how we can know what to remove. What if it is a `<li>` tag with no link inside? Will it always be the same link? Will you always have closing `</li>` tags as well?  Will the closing tag always be so far indented with multiple spaces at the beginning of the line? Will there be only one `<li>` and `</li>` tag per file or many?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear in the question. but the <li> is exactly the same as in the question above. There are other <li> tags in the file but they should be not replaced in anyway, only this exact <li> tag should be removed. am I clear?

Comment: As I asked before, ***please edit your question and add this information***. And please answer the other questions as well: will there only be one such case in each file? Will the indentation always be consistent? Could you have a case where you have everything from the `<li>` to the `</li>` on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the document fragment is part of a well formed XHTML file, you may delete all `li` nodes that contains an `a` node with a `href` attribute whose value is exactly `https://forward.global.ssl.fastly.net/contributoragreements/` using `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed --delete '//li[a/@href = "https://forward.global.ssl.fastly.net/contributoragreements/"]' file.xhtml
```

If the document is not a well formed XHTML document, you may attempt to recover it first:

```bsh
xmlstarlet fo --recover --html file.html |
xmlstarlet ed --delete '//li[a/@href = "https://forward.global.ssl.fastly.net/contributoragreements/"]'
```

To run this over all `index.html` files in a directory structure rotted at `top-dir`, call `xmlstarlet` from `find` like so:

```bsh
find top-dir -type f -name index.html -exec sh -c '
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    for pathname do
        cp "$pathname" "$tmpfile"
        xmlstarlet fo --recover --html "$tmpfile" |
        xmlstarlet ed --delete "//li[a/@href = \"https://forward.global.ssl.fastly.net/contributoragreements/\"]" >"$pathname.new"
    done
    rm -f "$tmpfile"' sh {} +
```

The above would create a new file called `index.html.new` for each found `index.html` file found.  You should look at these files and decide whether they look ok before running with `.new` removed from the command above.

You should obviously run this on a *copy* of your backed up data while testing.